# django, count and sum query

Tags: sql, django, orm, django-queryset

User can create a invitation.

Other users can accept the invitation.

I'd like to count the sum of accepted users for each inviter (user_invite)

```
Invitation

id, user_invite
-----------------
1,  a     
2,  a     
3,  a     
4,  b     
5,  b     

InvitationAccept

invitation, user_accept
-----------------
1,              c
1,              d
2,              e
4,              f
```

I'd like to get

```
user_invite,    accept_count
----------------------------
a                       3 (c,d,e)
b                       1 (f)
```

Django orm looks like

```
class Invitation:
    user_invite = models.ForeigneKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    invite_at = models.DateTimeField()
    accepts = generic.GenericRelation(InvitationAccept)

class InvitationAccept:

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    invitation = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    user_accept = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

What's the orm way of doing this? and sql equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `MySQL` you can utilize `GROUP_CONCAT` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to return `0 ()` for non-matched invitation:

```
SELECT i.user_invite,
   CONCAT(COUNT(ia.invitation), ' (',
          GROUP_CONCAT(user_accept ORDER BY user_accept),')') AS accept_count
FROM Invitation i
LEFT JOIN InvitationAccept ia
  ON i.id = ia.invitation
GROUP BY i.user_invite;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68cf3/6/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ user_invite  ║ accept_count ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════╣
║ a            ║ 3 (c,d,e)    ║
║ b            ║ 1 (f)        ║
╚══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

**EDIT:**

> actually I need just the count, (c,d,e) was only for the explanation.

Now the code is portable and ANSI compatible. It will work with most of RBDMS.

```
SELECT i.user_invite, COUNT(ia.invitation) AS accept_count
FROM Invitation i
LEFT JOIN InvitationAccept ia
  ON i.id = ia.invitation
GROUP BY i.user_invite;
```

Comment: oh thanks, actually I need just the count, (c,d,e) was only for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what database you are using so i tried this in MS SQL-SERVER

```
    select a.user_invite,cast(COUNT(1) as varchar) + '(' + ' ' +
    (STUFF((select ',' + user_accept from (select * from Invitation inv inner join InvitationAccept apct on inv.id = apct.invitation) b
    where b.user_invite=a.user_invite FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')) + ' ' + ')' as accept_count
    from (select * from Invitation inv inner join InvitationAccept apct on inv.id = apct.invitation) a
    group by a.user_invite
```

if you are using Oracle just try use other function maybe concat_ws() to replace the stuff part and || to replace the +.